# Merging a list of dicts in python based on common element

Tags: list, python-2.7, dictionary

So I have a list of dictionaries in Python as follows:

```
[
 {'medication_name': 'Actemra IV',
  'timeline': '2015-Jun',
  'total_prescriptions': 1
 },
 {'medication_name': 'Actemra IV',
  'timeline': '2015-Jul',
  'total_prescriptions': 0
 },
 {'medication_name': 'Adempas',
  'timeline': '2015-Jun',
  'total_prescriptions': 0
 },
 {'medication_name': 'Adempas',
  'timeline': '2015-Jul',
  'total_prescriptions': 0
 },
 {'medication_name': 'Adempas',
  'timeline': '2015-Aug',
  'total_prescriptions': 0
 },
 {'medication_name': 'Avonex',
  'timeline': '2015-Jun',
  'total_prescriptions': 1
 },
 {'medication_name': 'Avonex',
  'timeline': '2015-Jul',
  'total_prescriptions': 0
 }
]
```

What I would want is to collate the monthly values for each medication name so that the final result is as follows:

```
[
  {'medication_name': 'Actemra IV',
  'trend':[
           {'timeline': '2015-Jun',
            'total_prescriptions': 1
           },
           {'timeline': '2015-Jul',
            'total_prescriptions': 0
           },
           {'timeline': '2015-Jun',
            'total_prescriptions': 0
           }
         ]
 },
 {'medication_name': 'Adempas',
  'trend':[
           {'timeline': '2015-Jul',
            'total_prescriptions': 0
           },
           {'timeline': '2015-Aug',
            'total_prescriptions': 0
           }
         ]
 },
 {'medication_name': 'Avonex'
  'trend':[
           {'timeline': '2015-Jun',
            'total_prescriptions': 1
           },
           {'timeline': '2015-Jul',
            'total_prescriptions': 0
           }
         ]
  }
]
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (`meds` is the list with dicts):

```
tmp = {}
for med in meds:
    name = med.pop('medication_name')
    tmp.setdefault(name, []).append(med)
res = [{'medication_name': k, 'trend': v}  for k, v in tmp.items()]
```

Result:

```
>>> res
[{'medication_name': 'Avonex',
  'trend': [{'timeline': '2015-Jun', 'total_prescriptions': 1},
   {'timeline': '2015-Jul', 'total_prescriptions': 0}]},
 {'medication_name': 'Actemra IV',
  'trend': [{'timeline': '2015-Jun', 'total_prescriptions': 1},
   {'timeline': '2015-Jul', 'total_prescriptions': 0}]},
 {'medication_name': 'Adempas',
  'trend': [{'timeline': '2015-Jun', 'total_prescriptions': 0},
   {'timeline': '2015-Jul', 'total_prescriptions': 0},
   {'timeline': '2015-Aug', 'total_prescriptions': 0}]}]
```

### Note

This modifies the original data. You can use `copy.deepcopy()` to avoid this:

```
import copy

tmp = {}
for med in copy.deepcopy(meds):
    ...
```